# How to uninstall Outlook 2013 then reinstall using MSI script?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, outlook, windows-installer

Good morning,

Have rapidly reached the limits of my knowledge re: using MSIEXEC after having been asked to create a script that will uninstall Outlook 2013 and then reinstall it, using a batch file.

I created two .msp files using the MS Office customization tool, and on the test pc, placed them in C:\Program Files (x86)\Office2013_Admin\updates.

Next, have run through a number of attempts, some successful, most not, wrote

> c:\windows\system32\msiexec /p "C:\Program Files (x86)\Office2013_Admin\updates\NYSP_Disable_Outlook.MSP" /norestart /qb

and in trying to reinstall Outlook, wrote

> c:\windows\system32\msiexec /p "C:\Program Files (x86)\Office2013_Admin\updates\NYSP_Enable_Outlook.MSP" /n {90150000-002A-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE} /qb

Sure could use some help, please.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong, and am open to advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Really?  This is the level of engagement and support at stackoverflow?  The response has truly been ... impressive.